# Can I add a rectangle to a Jpanel in java swing and specify constraints for it using GridBagConstraints?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm pretty new to GUI and Java as a whole so I hope that I can explain this well enough and understand people's answers.

For a school project, I need to put a bunch of stuff on some rectangles but I'm having issues even adding one rectangle properly.

From researching online, this is what I have (the JPanel and GridBagConstraints are just there to show what I'd like to use):

```
public class GUI extends JPanel 
{

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        GUI g = new GUI();
        
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Java Window"); 
        window.setSize(1280, 960); 
        window.add(g);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        
        JPanel layout = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); 
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints(); 
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Color boxColour = new Color(194, 190, 190);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(boxColour);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

So right now, the rectangle appears in the window. But how can I add constraints to it? Is that possible? I would think that I should use JPanel to keep everything more organized since there will be many components so I tried adding this:

```
layout.add(g);
window.add(layout);
window.setVisible(true);
```

However, the rectangle no longer appeared. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it and add constraints to my shapes? Thanks!

Comment: There is a difference between "components", like `JPanel` and graphics primitives, like `Rectangle`.  My first guess is, you don't actually need `Rectangle`, instead you need to create custom `JPanel`s instead and use those, then you can make use of layout managers to organise them

Answer (score 0):

In your first scenario, the default layout manager of the frame is the `BorderLayout` and you are adding your "g" panel to the BorderLayout.CENTER. So based on the rules of the BorderLayout your "g" panel will take up all the space available in the frame. So you have plenty of space to paint your rectangle.

However, in your second scenario, your "layout" panel is using the default layout manager of a `JPanel` which is a `FlowLayout` which respects the preferred size of any component added to it.

The preferred size of the "g" panel is 10 x 10. So, when you add the "g" panel to the "layout" panel there is nothing to see because all you custom painting is done outside the bounds of the panel.

You need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your GUI panel to return a preferred size of (120, 120) so you can see your rectangle painted with a 10 pixel border around all the edges.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples demonstrating how to override the `getPreferredSize() method.

You will also need to read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for example of using the constraints to add multiple components.